# Is it good or bad practice to use an iFrame to insert a large amount of local content into a Lightbox?

Tags: php, forms, iframe, fancybox, ssi

I am creating an enquiry form which opens in a Fancybox pop-up but a little unsure as to how to correctly insert the content.

The form has a very large number of fields, so I think it would probably be best to have the code in a separate file, making it easier to read and be edited in the future, if the need ever arose.

I am aware I could create a separate file and include it into the page via PHP or SSI but wanted to get an opinion from others as to what the best way of getting the content in would be. I am veering away from changing the page which has the link to the form to .php (which is currently .shtml), as the website I'm working on is very old and doesn't have any PHP pages in it but does use SSI for the navigation and header sections (all pages in the site are .shtml).

Should I use SSI, an iFrame or just embed the code directly in the master page and forget keeping the form separate?

I look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: IMHO it's perfectly fine to have your form in a separated file and open it inside an iframe (iframe type) in fancybox. That file can be a htm, html, shtml, asp, aspx or php (or any other format that can be rendered by any browser) BTW, you don't need to include the file via php, just point at it in the `href` attribute of the anchor that is bound to fancybox

Comment: @JFK - great, thank you.